# Which is the best database for a cross domain recommendation engine?

Tags: cross-domain, freebase, recommendation-engine

If i have to correlate different Domains such as Movies/ Books/ Music then which database would be ideal for linking different domains? I tried Freebase but that does not correlate different domains.

Answer (score 0):

Might sound like a naive comment. Have you considered the possibility of coding the data from different domains rather than using the direct song/movie etc?

Comment: That is the last resort. However using different databases might not be the  best way since eventually linking them will be difficult (due to the absence of a lot of relevant common parameters)

Comment: Precisely. Throws me back to my earliest beginnings in recommender systems.. videos on coursera.. Imagine, Amazon - people who liked the book 'Persepolis' might want to buy the DVD of other revolution-related movies. If Amazon were to be running a recommender system keeping these information formats separate, that would be an inefficient means.  I'd rather en-code it. I mean, the matrix is already sparse, why add an additional layer of computational complexity and data access complexity as well - by keeping them in different formats.